# Number of pages of excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

Does anyone know how to get the number of total pages within a excel sheet via OpenXml? I do NOT need the number of sheets. I need the number of pages within a sheet.

Background:
We have to export multiple worksheets into a pdf file. Therefore we have to create a table of content.

Thanks!

EDIT-------

This is how it can be achieved via Office Interop:

```
var app = new MsExcel.Application();
var wb = app.Workbooks.Add(fullPath);

foreach (Worksheet sheet in wb.Sheets)
{
    sheet.Activate();
    string name = sheet.Name;
    int pages = sheet.PageSetup.Pages.Count;
}
```

It would be gread if someone knew a solution with **OpenXml**, **ClosedXml** or any other **free library**.

Thanks again!!!

Comment: How are the different “pages” defined on a single worksheet?

Comment: @JohnG: It's defined as the number of pages if we print it (A4).

Comment: Without more info it is difficult to proffer a solution. However, If the number of pages is defined as the number of “printed” pages from a worksheet, then the number of pages needed to print a worksheet is probably NOT “stored” as a property. I am confident the number of pages is a “calculated” value when the worksheet is printed. Therefore, I would assume your code is going to have to figure out how many pages are in the worksheet based on the print page size set in the workbook.

Comment: @JohnG: Thank you for your help. As you can see in the edited question I was able to find a solution. But I'm not totally happy with it.

Comment: Couldn't you find a solution without using interop?

Comment: Your Office Interop solution saved my life.